# instanceof Operator doesn't classify instance as a type

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

So I am running this code

```
function somefunc() { 
    return new WeakMap(); 
}

somefunc.prototype = new WeakSet();

var wm = new somefunc();

wm instanceof WeakMap //true
wm instanceof WeakSet //false
```

I wanted to ask why isn't `wm` an instance of `WeakSet`, because according to the example given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), `wm` should be an instance of `Weakset`.

Comment: Your `somefunc` is not a constructor - it returns an object

Comment: @Bergi so if a function return an object it is not a constructor ?

Comment: Yes, we call that a factory function. `wm` is the weak map created by `new WeakMap()`, despite being returned from the expression `new somefunc()`. Just doing `wm = somefunc()` would have exactly the same result

Comment: So is there anyway i can tweak this code to make wm an instanceof WeakSet ?

Comment: There are many ways, but they will all alter the behaviour. You cannot have a `WeakMap` that is also an instance of `WeakSet`.

Comment: Could you please point me towards the ways, behaviour alteration is ok. i just need the WeakMap to also be an instance of WeakSet

Comment: Just drop the `return new WeakMap();`  and instead create some properties (`this.foo = "bar";`). "*I need the WeakMap to also be an instance of WeakSet*" - as I just said, that's impossible. There is no multiple inheritance in JavaScript. An object cannot be both a `WeakMap` and a `WeakSet`. Maybe you should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) stating what problem you actually trying to solve.